# Prediction with Linear Regression

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

In this notebook, i want to predict how much the spending for cooking oil in one city for the next year. The independent variable is the years (2018-2021), and the dependent variable is the spending (in rupiah) in those years FROM ONE CITY. Like in this picture, i choose 'Simeulue' city to predict how much they would spent in 2022 and it was done, but it was from one city. How i can take those code to predict other city?

The point is i was doing single linear regression for the data in one city and i was confused to take those code to predict data from other city (513 city to be exact).
[firs pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ooy5.png)
[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8GCa.png)

Comment: where is your linear regression code? You need to one hot encode the city and use it in the regressor.

Comment: there i already edited the pic, first pic is the city, secnd is the linear regression code

Comment: To be frank your code is not comprehensive, can you put a reproducible code in text format (not picture). BTW any good linear regression tutorial will show how to use multiple independent (categorical columns also)